# JavaScript naming conventions with underscore

Tags: javascript

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031605/optimizing-websql-local-database-population/10031717#10031717), the answerer uses an underscore on line 3. If it were simply the start of a variable name, I'd be good with that.  But what does _(row) mean?

Comment: I think this is PHP. But I may be wrong

Comment: the question is answered right in his post and you commented on it. What's the point of posting this?

Comment: Oh, I see.  It's another JavaScript library called underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_` is [`underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).  `_` is a variable, it's a function, so you can do `_(rows)`.

In JavaScript, you can name variables whatever you want.  Such as `$` (jQuery) and `_`.

Comment: OK, thanks Rocket!  If I have jQuery loaded, I don't think I need underscore.  It looks like I can process it with the jQuery each command.

Answer (score 4):

It is the start of a variable name. It is also the end of a variable name. The variable (which has a function assigned to it) is `_`. The question references [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), which provides it.

Try, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/K6MN7/):

```
function _() { 
    alert('underscore!'); 
};
console.log(typeof _);
console.log(_);
_();​
```

Welcome to the wonderful world of completely unintuative variable names that are used because they are short and not alphanumeric. See also `$`, beloved of Prototype, jQuery and Mootools. In counterpoint, see [Self-documenting (code)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks Quentin!  I've heard of the underscore library in passing, but have never taken the time to read anything about it.